# Hardware Accelerated Audio

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-audio

I'm building an audio-based cordova app for iOS and the core app uses Knockout & jQuery. The app runs fine until the audio starts playing and then scrolling and on-screen animations become jumpy/laggy and the user-experience dwindles dramatically.

Is it possible to somehow hardware-accelerate HTML5 audio?

Comment: Have you read any specifications on HTML 5?

Comment: You don't want it hardware accelerated, you want it on a different thread/process/core whatever. This isn't your problem, but a browser implementation detail. i.e. it needs to be fixed in iOS not by your code. JS doesn't have enough access to the hardware to do this.

Comment: @RichBradshaw because the app is compiled through xcode is this something that can be changed/modified in xcode by an iOS developer?

Comment: Hmm, yes possibly. Might be pretty complex if its not already been done though. Perhaps ask on a Cordova irc room or forum.